# When use initializer and when use required argument

Tags: dart, oop

I saw these two class implementations and wonder what is the diffrence between in usage of them? and when to use each of them?

```
class A {
  B _b;
  A(B b) : _b = b;
}
class B{}
```

and the second variation is:

```
class A{
  B _b;
  A([B? b]) : _b = b ?? B();
}
class B{}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need an instance of class `B` to be created via class `A` you can use the `B` constructor in class `A`.
But when we want to keep the `B`'s state we can use the required parameter in the `A` constructor.

In the first variation, the `A` class does not create an instance of the `B` internally. Instead, it relies on an instance of the `B` to be injected via the constructor.

Comment: What about class B using the singleton design pattern to return the same constructed object every time it envokes?

Comment: How the `B()` constructor works doesn't change anything about whether the caller has to provide an instance of `B` or not. In the former variant, they must. In the latter variant, the caller can omit passing a `B` and just do `A()`.
Which API you want `A` to have should guide how you make it work.